# how to use '&' in URL Params for Rest Service Method

Tags: rest, wcf

I am using postman extension in chrome as RestClient.

My service url is as follows

```
 http://localhost:22/myserv.svc/InsertData?Id=1223&OffcName=my office&pid=2234
```

this is saving correct in db. Id=1223, OffcName=my offc and pid=2234

but if i want to use

```
http://localhost:22/myserv.svc/InsertData?Id=1223&OffcName=P&G pvt. ltd.&pid=2234
```

this is saving values as Id=1223, OffcName=P &pid=2234

I want to save full name with P&G. '&' is creating problem.

Please suggest something.

Answer (score 1):

Use [percent-encoding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) so encode `&` as `%26`

Comment: Thank you. This helped me. but out of curosity. What if i want to save '%26' in database. according to this it will always save '&' in database.

Comment: No, you need to follow a systematic encoding convention. so `%26` gets encoded as `%2526`